# Display elements on second level relationship in Nova Laravel using indexQuery

Tags: laravel-nova

I've 3 models

**User** has a hasmany relation (domains()) with **Domain** and this hasMany relation (mailboxes) with **Mailbox**

User.php

```
public function domains()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Domain::class);
}
```

Domain.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function mailboxes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Mailbox::class, 'domain', 'domain');
}
```

Mailbox.php

```
public function domains()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Domain', 'domain', 'domain');
}
```

Code below work fine for get only mailboxes owned but if put in policies not work.

```
public function view(User $user, Mailbox $mailbox)
{
    $domains = Domain::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('domain')->toArray();

    return User::with([
        'domains.mailboxes' => function ($builder) use ($domains) {
            $builder->where('domain',$domains);
        }
    ])->find($user);

}
```

I tried overrinding indexQuery on my Nova/Mailbox model, but not work. Retunr all mailboxes on database

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{

    $domains = Domain::where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->pluck('domain')->toArray();

    return User::with([
        'domains.mailboxes' => function ($builder) use ($domains) {
            $builder->where('domain',$domains);
        }
    ])->find($user);

    if ($request->user()->is_super_admin) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        return User::with([
            'domains.mailboxes' => function ($builder) use ($domains) {
                $builder->where('domain',$domains);
            }
        ])->find($user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `hasManyThrough` ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through)) relationship between User and Mailbox so you can pluck the mailboxes directly from the User model:

```php
# Inside User model class
public function mailboxes()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Mailbox::class, Domain::class, 'user_id', 'domain', 'id', 'domain');
}
```

Then in your indexQuery you could return the user with all its mailboxes:

```php
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->when(! $request->user()->is_super_admin, function ($builder) use ($request) {
        // Or use the request() method helper instead of use
        return $request->user()->with('mailboxes');
    });
}
```